# How to know which QObject::connect is failing

Tags: qt, qt-creator, signals-slots, qobject

I have an application with tens of signal slot connections, in particular multiple classes (with decomposition) are implementing almost identical `QObject::connect` signals to slots, the problem I am facing is sometimes, in QtCreator *Application Output*, I get the usual error:

> QObject::connect: Cannot connect
>   (null)::SessionClosed() to
>   mainWindow_Desktop::stop_Scanning()

But it lacks any indication from which file/line or code segment the error is coming from and the expense of that is I have to check all similar connections to detect which one went in error!
my question is:  I**s there any way to directly know the file/line the error refers to**?

Comment: Use assert for every connection that is not marked as `Qt::UniqueConnection`. `assert(connect(...))`

Comment: You may install an [event filter on qWarning](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler) and call an assert/throw exception or whatever you like, to handle all similar situations.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov, The issue is worse and I didn't probably describe it enough, the errors are coming from classes that are never instantiated .. they have no object at run time due to their polymorphic structure

Comment: @Jaa-c `assert` will become a no-op once you build in release mode (see `NDEBUG` macro). Happy debugging in this case :)

Comment: @Ruslan: Internal release versions for testing purposes usually have asserts... And for production code, you turn them off...

Comment: @Jaa-c right, and with them go away all calls to `connect`, if we follow the form suggested in your original comment. And then you have to debug the production version, failing to reproduce the problem with debug one and internal release one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect()` has a return value, which comes with an implicit bool conversion operator, so you can simply test whether it succeeded with an `if` statement and if necessary issue a warning that can tell you where it happens if verbose warnings are enabled.

Naturally you can manually use the `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` and `__FUNCTION__` macros yourself.

Comment: Thanks. If I read you correctly, this approach, has no limitation .. of being a debug only tool .. I don't _see_ it impractical to go in production.

Comment: Yes, it is purely a runtime thing, you can take different code paths depending on the return value, implement error checking, fixing, mitigation, termination, arbitrary data output and naturally set breakpoints that would otherwise not be reached.

Answer (score 2):

Set breakpoints on `QMessageLogger::warning`, `QMessageLogger::critical` etc.. Then you'll have your application stopped on such messages by `qWarning`, `qCritical` etc. from Qt, and call stack will tell you where they originate.

Example code:

```
#include <QObject>

void f()
{
    QObject::connect(0,"kkk",0,"aaa");
}

int main()
{
    f();
}
```

After compiling, when I run it with GDB, I get:

```
$ gdb -ex 'set breakpoint pending on' -ex 'b QMessageLogger::warning' \
      -ex r -ex bt ./test
Reading symbols from ./test...done.
Function "QMessageLogger::warning" not defined.
Breakpoint 1 (QMessageLogger::warning) pending.
Starting program: /tmp/test/test 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, QMessageLogger::warning (this=this@entry=0x7fffffffd2e0, msg=msg@entry=0x7ffff7c3ac80 "QObject::connect: Cannot connect %s::%s to %s::%s") at global/qlogging.cpp:541
541     {
#0  QMessageLogger::warning (this=this@entry=0x7fffffffd2e0, msg=msg@entry=0x7ffff7c3ac80 "QObject::connect: Cannot connect %s::%s to %s::%s") at global/qlogging.cpp:541
#1  0x00007ffff7b64a4d in QObject::connect (sender=0x0, signal=0x400838 "kkk", receiver=<optimized out>, method=<optimized out>, type=<optimized out>) at kernel/qobject.cpp:2618
#2  0x0000000000400788 in f () at test.cpp:5
#3  0x00000000004007a0 in main () at test.cpp:10
```

Here we can see that the bad call to `connect` occurs in `test.cpp:5` in `f()`.

Comment: I am trying it out. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like it will end up catching pretty much every source of warning rather than isolate connection problems. Not to mention requiring slower and larger debug builds.

Comment: @dtech what do you mean by slower? You can optimize however you want, but include debug info to be able to locate the point where `connect` is called. As Qt functions are almost never inlined, optimization shouldn't be a complication.

Comment: I mean debug builds are huge, take much longer to build, take much longer to start and execute much slower. So definitely not an optional scenario if all you want to know is whether a connection fails. Debug builds are for... debugging :)